# I don't have fixed IP address, how can I let others access my database?

Tags: memgraphdb

I run Memgraph Platform on my laptop inside Docker container. When I'm at the office my colleague can access it, but when I work from home he can not get to the database. I don't have fixed IP address, and my ISP doesn't allow me to do port forwarding and dynamic DNS also doesn't work for me. What can I do to make my database accessible to others?

Comment: Tailscale, zerotier, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to follow the advice given by @Martheen. I have experience with running [Tailscale](https://tailscale.com/) for this purpose and it works.

I don't know why you can't deploy it to some server (if there are regulation issues or company policies in question) but if it is not any of those maybe you could use [Memgraph Cloud](https://memgraph.com/cloud) and host your data. That way you would be sure that everyone with the right credentials could access your data. But it all depends on your setup and usage scenario. Since you are using Docker I presume that you have all of your environment configured right the way that you want on your laptop.